# jersey error java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class in jetty embedded

Tags: jersey, embedded-jetty

running jersey 2.5.1 and embedding jetty jetty-9.1.2.v20140210

I want an embedded jetty server capable of servlet 3x as well as jersey. I know that my jetty instance works as servlet handler and static file hander. however the following details I get this error:
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

I am sure it is related to cglib / asm but not sure how to fix it.

The pom looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedjettyX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>embedjettyX</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>        
        <jersey.version>2.5.1</jersey.version>                       
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.9</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--         <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.2.v20140210</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.2.v20140210</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>

        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-deploy</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.2.v20140210</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

the rest app class like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application() {
        packages("quintes.rest");      
    }


}
```

the REST resource:

```
@Path("test")
public class restresource {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getDefault() {
        return Response.ok("test returned").build();
    }

}
```

and the main() like this:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server server = new Server(8081);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);


        ServletHolder servletHolder = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/api/*");
        servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass",
                "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");

        servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "quintes.rest");

        ServletHolder staticServlet = context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/*");
        staticServlet.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "src/main/webapp");
        staticServlet.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

however I get the error mentioned as part of this stack trace:

```
2014-06-23 09:26:49.502:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp28971452-13: Error for /api/
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:875)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:840)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1171)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1140)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:299)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:359)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:424)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:690)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What am i doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: I have a similar problem. Java 8, Groovy 1.8.6, Ubuntu `16.04.1 LTS`. I'm guessing I just have to mess with the jersey library version.